# Update issue in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I try to update documents using the update api, the following error is popping up

```
{"error":"RemoteTransportExceptiones-node9][inet[/10.130.89.220:9300[indices:data/write/update]]; nested: VersionConflictEngineExceptionnewsentiments][3] [relevancy][abc@gmail.com]: version conflict, current [71], provided [70; ","status":409}
```

What is causing the above error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send your request you specify the version of the doc you want to update ? Something like:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myIndex/MyType/1?version=70' -d '{
    "content" : "here is my update"
}'
```

The issue is someone (or you) already updated the version 70 so now the version is 71.
To resolve your issue, just don't pass the version in the request:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myIndex/MyType/1' -d '{
    "content" : "here is my update"
}'
```